# Init from decoder in a protocol extension gives error "'self' used before 'self.init' call or assignment to 'self'"

Tags: swift, protocols, codable

I would like to decode a an extension of protocol:

```
protocol SettingsContentProtocol: Codable {
    var audioDelegate:AudioDelegate? { get set }
    var isPlaying: Bool { get set }
    var meditationTimes: [MeditationItem: TimeInterval] {get set}
    var intermediate: Int {get set}
    var contentsDuration: Float {get set}
    var durata:TimeInterval {get set}
    var parzialeDurata:TimeInterval {get set}
    var date: Date {get set}
    var hour: Int {get}
    var followDuration: TimeInterval {get set}

    func selectPeriod(item:MeditationItem)
    mutating func sliderMoved(item: MeditationItem, sliderPosition: Float)
    func calculateContentsDuration()->Float
    func tooShortTimeForContents(completion:@escaping ((Bool)->Void))
    func cleanQueue(items:[MPMediaItem])
    func selectRow(indexPath: IndexPath)
    func tableEdit(indexPath: IndexPath)
    func rowAt(indexPath: IndexPath, tableView: UITableView)->UITableViewCell
    mutating func adjustProgress(progress: TimeInterval)
    mutating func prepareMeditation()
    func meditationDetails()->Meditation
    func meditationMessage(final: Bool)->String
    func meditationTime()->String
}
```

with:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    isPlaying = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isPlaying)
    meditationTimes = try container.decode([MeditationItem: TimeInterval].self, forKey: .meditationTimes)
    intermediate=try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .intermediate)
    contentsDuration=try container.decode(Float.self, forKey: .contentsDuration)
    durata=try container.decode(TimeInterval.self, forKey: .durata)
    parzialeDurata=try container.decode(TimeInterval.self, forKey: .parzialeDurata)
    date=try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
    followDuration=try container.decode(TimeInterval.self, forKey: .followDuration)
}
```

Yet, when I compile I get on each line error:

> "'self' used before 'self.init' call or assignment to 'self'"

All the examples I found seem to agree with my code, what might be wrong instead?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: That is the function returning the error. It is part of an extension of a protocol, I think it would make little sense to present the full class and protocol, but if you want I may of course do it.

Comment: Since you are doing this in a protocol it is exactly as the error says, you are assigning a value to a property but since there is no object yet there is no property. Init methods needs to work on an object created from a struct or a class

Comment: You need to include the minimal amount of code that I need, such that I can copy and paste into Xcode, or the minimal number of steps that I can take, in order see the error that you describe. Right now, you don't have a minimal reproducible example. Where does `CodingKeys` come from?

Comment: The `Codable` implementation you have shown here seems to the standard boilerplate, which can be synthesised by Swift. You don't need the protocol extension.

Comment: I am not using JSON, I am saving on iCloud. At any rate all items are of course codable by themselves. The extension is needed to implement common features of the protocol adopting structs. If I remove the init and encode, Xcode itself sets them as stubs. As for the first comment, how do I create the object in a protocol extension, but by assigning their values? If I put self.init() at the beginning, it suggests me to add the (from:) parameter thus producing a loop.

Comment: Moreover, examples like those at: https://medium.com/@pleelaprasad/codable-protocols-in-swift-76f8b088c483 seem to reproduce my code, albeit not in a protocol extension.

Comment: _"albeit not in a protocol extension"_, but that is main point. You can not do it in a protocol extension like that, it has to be an extension to a class or struct.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed by setting a standard init() in the protocol each adopting struct of course adopts, and I called it from the init(from:) as follows:

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws{
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(isPlaying, forKey: .isPlaying)
    try container.encode(meditationTimes, forKey: .meditationTimes)
    try container.encode(intermediate, forKey: .intermediate)
    try container.encode(durata, forKey: .durata)
    try container.encode(parzialeDurata, forKey: .parzialeDurata)
    try container.encode(date, forKey: .date)
    try container.encode(followDuration, forKey: .followDuration)
}


init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    self.init()
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    isPlaying = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isPlaying)
    meditationTimes = try container.decode([MeditationItem: TimeInterval].self, forKey: .meditationTimes)
    intermediate=try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .intermediate)
    durata=try container.decode(TimeInterval.self, forKey: .durata)
    parzialeDurata=try container.decode(TimeInterval.self, forKey: .parzialeDurata)
    date=try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
    followDuration=try container.decode(TimeInterval.self, forKey: .followDuration)
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a custom encoder and decoder at first place?

Comment: Because it is requested by the compiler. Frankly I think you should query Apple.